# ggplot2 boxplot stat_summary text placement by group

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2, boxplot, facet

In the plot below, I'd like the number of observations (40 in this case) to be overlayed on top of each boxplot. My code below doesn't work when there's a `fill` aesthetic. The text need to be adjusted horizontally (1 left, 1 center, 1 right in this case) so that they properly overlay their corresponding boxplots.

```r
dt <- data.table(
    x = factor(rep(1:2, each=120))
    , f = rep(letters[1:3], 40)
    , y = c(rnorm(120, 1:3), rnorm(120, 1:3*2))
)
table(dt$x, dt$f)

+--------------+
|      a  b  c |
+--------------+
|   1 40 40 40 |
|   2 40 40 40 |
+--------------+

frequencyAnnotation <- function(x) {
   c(y = (quantile(x, .75, names = F) + median(x))/2, label=length(x))
}
ggplot(dt, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=f)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    stat_summary(fun.data = frequencyAnnotation, geom='text')
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your boxplots are dodged when you use argument fill=, you have to add `position_dodge()` to the `stat_summary()` call.

```
ggplot(dt, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=f)) +
      geom_boxplot() +
      stat_summary(fun.data = frequencyAnnotation, geom='text', 
                   position = position_dodge(width = 0.75))
```

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't encountered `position_dodge()` yet. It's not a big concern, but is there a way to avoid hardcoding the `width = 0.75`? i.e. can you do it programmatically?

Comment: For the boxplots and text this 0.75 will not change if you change number of x and f levels.

Comment: That's magical. Is there a simple explanation why? If not, thanks anyways - it works great!

Comment: 0.75 is default value for `postion_dodge()` for boxplots when you use fill, so you have to use the same value also for text.